# Run files with other extensions as .php files on apache2 server

Tags: php, apache

I'm currently running PHP & Apache2 installed on Ubuntu Server 20.04

```
Ubuntu Server 20.04
Server version: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
PHP 7.4.10 (cli) (built: Sep  9 2020 06:36:14) ( NTS )
```

I remember being able to run files with other extensions as `.php` files on older version of `php` and `apache`. Eg: Back then, I was able to save a file containing `php` script as something like `file_name.load`, and then add the `.load` extension somewhere in the apache2 or php configuration, and it would run `.load` just as a php file.

How is this done now?

P.S I can't do it with htaccess. Have to use the apache2 or php config files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add under `conf/httpd.conf`

`AddType application/x-httpd-php .load`